# Can any finite subset of Lebesgue measurable set be ordered?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I am trying to solve this problem:

Suppose a function $f$ has a measurable domain and is continuous except at a finite number of points. Is $f$ necessarily measurable?

And I am reading this solution here [Is $f$ necessarily measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388727/is-f-necessarily-measurable/804446#804446) :

"What about this for the first question:

Let $A$ be the measurable domain of $f$ and let $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be the finite collection of discontinuities. Since $|X|$ is finite, we can order them from smallest, say $x_1$, to largest, say $x_n$. Then for $1\le i\le n+1$ define
$$
A_i=A\cap (x_{i-1},x_i),
$$
where $x_0=-\infty$ and $x_{n+1}=\infty$. Observe that each $A_i$ is measurable and
$$
\{x\in A\,:\, f(x)>c\}=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}\{x\in A_i\,:\, f(x)>c\}\right) \cup \{x\in X\,:\,f(x)>c\}
$$
For each $c$, each set in the indexed union is measurable (because $f$ is measurable on each A_i) and each subset of $X$ is either empty or contains no more than $n$ points and is therefore measurable as well."

**But I have the following question:**

Can any finite subset of Lebesgue measurable set be ordered? If so, why?

Comment: Any finite set whatsoever can be ordered. (Note that "ordered" is meant in a specific sense here: what's needed for the proof is that for every finite set of reals $X$ there is some natural number $n$ and some bijection $f:X\rightarrow\{1,...,n\}$ such that $x<y\iff f(x)<f(y)$.)

Comment: How do you know this? is there a theorem about this?@NoahSchweber

Comment: Think about what "finite" **means** in the first place ...